# Plugin or Extensions - DOM elements - .value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Are there any extensions for the Google Chrome browser or command to receive the value of the value property with a notation when clicking on an element with point notification, if the data transfer is in sort order and has a hierarchical structure

Example - 
[image]

and result, to easily make such nested elements:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. Your pictures do not explain what you want to see

Comment: Thanks. I realized